# how can I send emails where the subject has special characters?

Tags: php, html

when I send the email, if the subject says "Ç", it shows "?".

already tried to implement:

-charset="ascii";

-charset=UTF-8;

-$mail->$subject = "=?ISO-8859-1?Q?".imap_8bit("äöüßÄÖÜ sollte hier gehen")."?=";

-$mail->$subject = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode(utf8_encode("çççç")).'?=';

So far I can not solve this, what else can I do? I already searched in the forum has a lot of post to talk about it but none solved my problem.

My exemple code is :

```html
$mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->charset="UTF-8";
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "*.*.*.*:*";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
    $mail->From = "*@*.*";
    $mail->FromName = "newjob";  
    $mail->addAddress($add1, $addnome1);
    if($add2!=""){ $mail->addAddress($add2, $addnome2);};  
    if($add3!=""){ $mail->addAddress($add3, $addnome3);};  
    $mail->ContentType = 'text/calendar; charset=utf-8';
    $mail->$subject = "=?ISO-8859-1?Q?".imap_8bit("äöüßÄÖÜ")."?=";
    // $mail->$subject = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode(utf8_encode("çççç")).'?=';
    
    $ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n";
    $ical .= "VERSION:2.0\r\n";
    $ical .= "PRODID:-sigma.eda.pt\r\n";
    $ical .= "METHOD:PUBLISH\r\n";
    $ical .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n";
    $ical .= "ORGANIZER;SENT-BY=\"MAILTO:$add1\r\n";
    $ical .= "ATTENDEE;CN=$add1;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=false:mailto:$add1\r\n";
    $ical .= "UID:".strtoupper(md5($event_id))."-sigma.eda.pt\r\n";
    $ical .= "SEQUENCE:".$sequence."\r\n";
    $ical .= "STATUS:".$status."\r\n";
    $ical .= "DTSTAMPTZID=Europe/azores:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."\r\n";
    $ical .= "DTSTART:".$start."T".$start_time."\r\n";
    $ical .= "DTEND:".$end."T".$end_time."\r\n";
    $ical .= "LOCATION:".$venue."\r\n";
    $ical .= "SUMMARY:".$summary."\r\n";
    $ical .= "DESCRIPTION:".$descr."\r\n";
    $ical .= "RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=".$rotina.";COUNT=".$repete.";\r\n";
    $ical .= "BEGIN:VALARM\r\n";
    $ical .= "TRIGGER:-PT15M\r\n";
    $ical .= "ACTION:DISPLAY\r\n";
    $ical .= "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\r\n";
    $ical .= "END:VALARM\r\n";
    $ical .= "END:VEVENT\r\n";
    $ical .= "END:VCALENDAR\r\n";
    $mail->Body = $ical;
      try {
       if ( !$mail->Send() ) {
        //  $error = "Unable to send the email <br />";
        //  throw new phpmailerAppException($error);
       } else {
        //  echo 'Message has been sent<br /><br />';
       }
     } catch (phpmailerAppException $e) {
      //  $errorMsg[] = $e->errorMessage();
     }
```

**EDIT**
image error from test:

[image: here]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has case sensitive class properties, which means that when a property has a name `CharSet`, it has to be defined like this and not in lowercase `$mail->charset`. This also aplies to `$mail->$subject` <strike>and `$mail->addAddress`</strike>, `addAddress` case is like this. Here is an example with greek text that's working without any text conversion:

**EDIT**

I've tested this code above and it's working:

```
$email = 'some@email.com';
$message =  'Όνομα: <br/>'.
    'eMail: <br/>'.
    'Τηλέφωνο: <br/>'.
    '(Ç, ç, äöüßÄÖÜ sollte hier gehen, açores)';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    $mail->isMail();
    $mail->addAddress($email);
    $mail->setFrom('test@email.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->CharSet = PHPMailer::CHARSET_UTF8;
    $mail->Subject = "[ΣΥΜΜΕΤΟΧΗ] Νέα φόρμα δήλωσης συμμετοχής (Ç, ç, äöüßÄÖÜ sollte hier gehen, açores)";

    $mail->msgHTML($message);
    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

And here is the screenshot of the received email:

[image: Result email screenshot]

Comment: that's a correct answer, my problem was case sensitive, really tanks for the help mate

Comment: well...
your answer was right, I really had a character problem, but the problem of the letters "ç, á, é" and others are not showing in the subject of the email, but your example works perfect .... why ?

Comment: @NoobDEV-GBL because your file encoding isn't of `UTF-8`, maybe it's `ANSI` or something else.

Comment: please explain better, what file are you talking about?

Comment: The file you have the code/text saved in. It has to be `UTF8` encoded or else it will destroy all unicode characters from something like this `Ç` to this `?`.

Comment: Check my updated code which I've tested and it's working. I also provide the received email screenshot for you to see.

Comment: if i copy and paste your

 "$mail->Subject = "[ΣΥΜΜΕΤΟΧΗ] Νέα φόρμα δήλωσης συμμετοχής (Ç, ç, äöüßÄÖÜ sollte hier gehen, açores)";" 

or   "$mail->Subject = "[ΣΥΜΜΕΤΟΧΗ] , açores)";"

it works fine, but if i use text like :

$mail->Subject = "açores";

Don't, and i dont know way....

Comment: this is a client name " new job for eletrecidade dos açores" is the Subject

Comment: what version of phpmailer you are using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version [v6.0.7](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/releases/tag/v6.0.7). It works just fine for me when I'm setting *"açores"* as the `Subject`, here is a screenshot: [PHPMailer Encoding Screenshot](https://zikro.gr/dbg/so/55615675/so-phpmailer-encoding.png). Which IDE/Editor do you use to edit the source code PHP file? Are you sure you're saving the file with `UTF-8` encoding?

Comment: well you got me, my lib was PHPMailer_5.2.0, thats my  problem, i have made the update and now is working fine, like my name say, noob dev

Comment: @NoobDEV-GBL glad you found the culprit. It can happen to everyone and remember, the most advanced devs were noob devs when they began writing code!

Comment: you are right.

Please can you help me converting ical to this new version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191747/discussion-between-christos-lytras-and-noobdev-gbl).